# How to prevent a container from shutting down during an error?

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

Everytime I make a mistake or something in my code, the container is shutting down and leaves me with `shotel_backend exited with code 1`. How to prevent it?

Here's Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN pip install pipenv

RUN mkdir /backend
WORKDIR /backend

ADD Pipfile Pipfile.lock /backend/
RUN pipenv install

ADD . /backend/
```

and here docker-compose

```
version: '3'

services:
    backend:
        container_name: shotel_backend
        build: ./backend
        volumes:
            - ./backend/:/backend
        working_dir: /backend/
        command: pipenv run python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the following under the container in docker compose?

`command: sleep infinity`

It will keep the container up so you can edit your code.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, in case someone else has this problem.

It is not pretty, but this is what I do

1. rename `command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` in `docker-compose.yaml`. What this command does is very much nothing. It keeps the process running for 20 hours (hopefully you take a break from coding after that :) ), but no real work is being done. The reason why one has to do that, is because the docker container will shut down when the command being run ends (or crashes), so `sleep 20h` just keeps the container alive for 20 hours. You can also do something similar if you are working only with one container via a `Dockerfile` by replacing `CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` with `CMD sleep 20`
2. Build/launch your containers and attach the dev container in vs code
3. Open a terminal window, and start a shell with `docker exec -it <name_of_your_container> bash` (or sh, or whatever shell you use)
4. In the terminal window from 2. , run `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`. This will run the django server
5. Code away... if you made a typo or error, the django server in the terminal from 2. will crash, but the container will not. Just fix your error, and re-run python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` again when you are done

In case you are using the `docker-compose.yaml` to deploy the django app, remember to change the `command` to whatever you need to run then

Answer (score 0):

Every docker container is essentially running only one main process - that is the ENTRYPOINT and/or CMD at the end of the Dockerfile.

If what you want is for your desired process to restart without having to restart your container altogether then you will have to use a process manager like supervisord.

More info and workarounds for what you are looking for are given [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/).

I would however still recommend that you prevent your process from exiting with proper exception handling in the first place.

Comment: By saying "mistake" I mean "typo" etc.

Answer (score -1):

All you have todo is use this policy in your docker-compose:

`restart: always`

But I would suggest you to find and fix the error in your code.

EDIT: I forgot to say that this doesn't prevent shutting down the container, all it does is automatically restart it in case of error.

Comment: idk how should it work but it doesn't. I want to prevent shutting down and reload server on change.

Comment: Another DIRTY way to "prevent it" is to start the container with another process (one that never dies, such as bash) and then start your process. But, this is not the proper way to do it.